# How do make a variable-width input field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the label and input field appear on the same line, with a variable width input field that will expand based on the space available

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/WcQ6J/

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <aside>foo</aside>
    <span><input type="text" value="Enter text" /></span>
</div>

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

aside {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

It works fine with a span, but when I add input it wraps to next line.

Comment: You could use `display: table-*`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/WcQ6J/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some whacky solution. I honestly don't really understand why this works. I had it in an old codepen. Good luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/DD73r/

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="label-w">
    <label for="your-input">your label</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-w">
    <input name="your-input" placeholder="your stuff" />
  </div>

</div> <!-- .container -->
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 2em;
}

.label-w {
  width: 8em;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.input-w {
  float: none; /* key */
  width: auto; /* key */
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* key */
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.input-w input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How about a text indent and an absolute positioned label about the size of that indent?

Comment: The key here was adding `overflow: hidden` to the input wrapper. Not sure what side effects that creates, but works for now.

Comment: You should try throwing a micro clear fix on that and see if it acts the same.

Comment: The overflow:hidden trick creates the side-effect that you lose control over the input field's borders. The right-most border will never be shown, for example. Try adding margins to the input field and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CSS [calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/#calc-notation) property to determine the width minus the borders and aside width:

```
input {
  width: calc(100% - 102px); /* 100% minus (aside width (100px) + border width (2px)) */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WcQ6J/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `display: table-*`:

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
aside {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #bbb;
}
input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/WcQ6J/5/

This is a little bit more compatible (and flexible) that `display: inline-block`, which is not supported in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the "aside" to pixels and the span to a percent, but, as you've seen, that will cause problems. It's easier to set both to a percent. Also, "inline-block" will put your elements in line. You can use this or "float: right;", but I prefer setting the display.

```
aside {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9%;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXUdW/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a truly variable width input field, so that you can manually adjust its width to fill the entire page, or to any other convenient width, why not make that input element fill 100 % of a resizable div?

CSS:

```
<style>
   div.resize {
      width: 300px; /*initial width*/
      resize: horizontal;
      overflow: auto;
   }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="resize">
   <input style="width: 100%" />
```

The little triangle to drag to resize the div will appear in the lower-right corner of the input element!